# Material ui Loading Button Loads all button onClick in React js loop (using map)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, commerce, commerce.js

So, I was working on commerce.js API. But when I press add to cart, it takes a bit of time to update the cart items number (from API) so I thought I should add a loading button until the cart items load. I found LoadingButton from **@mui/lab** so I used it. but the problem is even though that button is inside the loop when pressing onClick all the other button also goes to the loading state. IDK am I missing something or is my coding false?. Please check below & help me. Thanks. :) 
***Here is the main problem.***

[image: material ui]

Here is the app.js where you can see loading state & other API fetching
[image]

products component in app.js. you can see I passed down the products & loading props 
[image]

products loop & props down to product component 
[image]

finally the cart loading button in the product component with loading props. it works but all other buttons also loads at the same time. 
[image]

Comment: Did you tried passing key to `<Products />` ?

Comment: you mean key prop? I did pass it you can see above.

Comment: And sharing a working example of your code would be very helpful @Tauhid

Comment: Please edit the question to have the code instead of images. It would be so much easier to work it around. @Tauhid

Comment: Well, I thought MUI <LoadingButton> loading prop does that. because it checks true or false. I should not have to add logic I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a map in which you store the loading state for each cart. So `cartLoading` will have the following shape:

```js
{
  "product-one-id": true,
  "product-two-id": false,
}
```

So change the state to `const [cartLoading, setCartLoading] = useState({});`

At `handleAddToCart`, change the two `setCartLoading` calls so that they update only one key of the state:

```js
setCartLoading(oldState => ({...oldState, [productId]: true}));
...
setCartLoading(oldState => ({...oldState, [productId]: false}));
```

Then, at the `<Grid>` inside the `Products` component, change `cartLoading={cartLoading}` to `cartLoading={cartLoading[product.id] || false}`

This is just one way to do it though. You can also handle the state inside your `Product` component.

Answer (score 1):

You use single one (let's say "global") variable for specifing loader state which doesn't allow you to check which one product fired cart loading.

```js
/* ... */
const [cartLoading, setCartLoading] = useState(false);
/* ... */
```

First of all consider if you need information about updating cart somewhere else than in buttons. If not then the best option could be use useState inside `<Product />` component for specific product instead of `<App />`.